# Run a script on shutdown

Tags: release-loki, shutdown, script

I have a very simple script that I want to run every time I shut down my computer.

How can the script be automatically executed once I press the 'Shut Down' or 'Restart' button?

Comment: By the way, I think it'd be nice to have a user-friendly interface for this feature, that is in System Settings > Application add the option 'Shut Down' next to 'Default' and 'Startup' :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know of a real graphical way to achieve that.

But because elementary is based on Ubuntu and thus uses systemd, you should be able to do it with a systemd service. Basically create a file `/etc/systemd/system/myshutdown.service` with something like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do something on shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path/to/your/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable it with: `systemctl enable myshutdown`

Comment: I had some problems with the 'service' suffix that it's needed in the file name but not in the command "systemctl enable". Moreover, as it's written in the blog cited in the other reply, the first time I shut down the script didn't run, but it ran the next times